# Error thrown if I don't validate form first before adding a rule in jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Please tell me what's going on with my jquery validation checking?

I have added a rule

```
$('#zipCodeText').rules("add", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 5,
    messages: {
        required: "Required input",
        minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
        maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary")
    }
});
```

but if I don't call `.validate()` on the form first, the `jquery.validate.js` file throws and error on line 147 saying `"Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference"`

If I call `.validate()` on the form then there is no error!

This doesn't make any sense because I have another page where I have a form and I don't have to call validate first to add a rule, and then use `.valid()` to check that rule if I submit

Is the library getting hung up somewhere or does it somehow need to be reset or something?

Answer (score 0):

> but if I don't call `.validate()` on the form first, the `jquery.validate.js` file throws and error on line 147 saying "Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference"
>
> If I call `.validate()` on the form then there is no error!

Yes, because you **cannot** call the `.rules()` method before the plugin has been *initialized* on your form!

> This doesn't make any sense because I have another page where I have a form and I don't have to call validate first to add a rule, and then use `.valid()` to check that rule if I submit.

That is impossible and you've shown us no code that disputes it.  You **must** call `.validate()` to initialize the plugin before calling the `.valid()` method.

[Quoting the documentation for `.valid()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/):

> `validate()` needs to be called on the form before checking it using this method.